# Why my GWAS p-value QQ-plot falls far above diagonal?

Tags: qq-plot, bioinformatics, gwas

I'm trying to run GWAS pipeline using plink, but the results I got look really off. The QQ-plot of the p-values is far above the diagonal.

I'm pretty sure I followed the correct QC process, and the inclusion of covariates is probably also not a major cause since with and without covariates I got very similar QQ-plots which look wrong (attached below).

Does anyone have experience with this and know what's going wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is there more data than shown on the graph? Set the y-axis maximum to automatic...

Comment: Wow! Are the training and test set different? We can see even with the truncated Y axis (not the cause) that this is unusual.

Comment: The p-values are not independent. This QQ plot looks as I would have expected. Have you made a [Manhattan plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_plot) of the results?